# In SQL How can I show a different value if some columns return ‘Y’, ‘N’ OR ‘L’,

Tags: sql

How can I show a different value if some columns return ‘Y’, ‘N’ OR ‘L’,
for example,
COLUMN "INACT_IND" returns ‘Y’, but I need show for the user ‘NOT ACTIVE’. Case ‘Y’, return ‘NOT ACTIVE’.

I did a CASE function but it returned an error, my code is below:

```
select USR.LOGIN_ID, USR.NAME, "Active or Inactive" = (USR.INACT_IND), 
"Created Date" = (USR.REC_CREATE_DATE)
FROM USR
where 
CASE 
WHEN USR.INACT_IND='N' THEN 'ACTIVE'
WHEN USR.INACT_IND='Y' THEN 'NOT ACTIVE'
WHEN USR.INACT_IND='L' THEN 'LOCKED'
END
```

Comment: Well the CASE needs to be in the SELECT list if you want it selected, not in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3):

The CASE should be in your SELECT statement, before the FROM:

```
SELECT USR.LOGIN_ID, USR.NAME, USR.REC_CREATE_DATE AS CREATE_DATE,
CASE 
WHEN USR.INACT_IND='N' THEN 'ACTIVE'
WHEN USR.INACT_IND='Y' THEN 'NOT ACTIVE'
WHEN USR.INACT_IND='L' THEN 'LOCKED'
END AS A_I
FROM USR
```

Also, you need to use AS to define your column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
select USR.LOGIN_ID,
   USR.NAME,
   "Active or Inactive" = (CASE
     WHEN USR.INACT_IND = 'N' THEN
      'ACTIVE'
     WHEN USR.INACT_IND = 'Y' THEN
      'NOT ACTIVE'
     WHEN USR.INACT_IND = 'L' THEN
      'LOCKED'
   END),
   "Created Date" = (USR.REC_CREATE_DATE)
FROM USR
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your case statement in the wrong line

```
   select USR.LOGIN_ID, 
          USR.NAME, 
          USR.INACT_IND AS ActiveOrInactive, -- This is an Alias
          USR.REC_CREATE_DATE as CreatedDate -- This is an alias
          CASE 
                WHEN USR.INACT_IND='N' THEN 'ACTIVE'
                WHEN USR.INACT_IND='Y' THEN 'NOT ACTIVE'
                WHEN USR.INACT_IND='L' THEN 'LOCKED'
                Else USR.INACT
                END as Indicator

    FROM USR
```

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement. (It returns a value.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want rows with only 'N', 'Y' and 'L' USR.INACT_IND values? If not, remove the `WHERE` clause:

```
select USR.LOGIN_ID, USR.NAME, USR.INACT_IND as "Active or Inactive",
       USR.REC_CREATE_DATE as CREATE_DATE,
       CASE USR.INACT_IND
           WHEN 'N' THEN 'ACTIVE'
           WHEN 'Y' THEN 'NOT ACTIVE'
           WHEN 'L' THEN 'LOCKED'
       END
FROM USR
WHERE USR.INACT_IND IN ('N', 'Y', 'L')
```

**Note:** This is *simple case* expression saves some typing!